# how can we make a matrix in arraylist with java

Tags: java, arrays, matrix, collections

how to make a matrix in arraylist Java I was solving some problem where they have used reverse function with the matrix collection.reverse(); but I don't know how to make a matrix with array list and I'm unable to find it anywhere.

Comment: Just make a list of lists?

Comment: with that would I'll be able to use reverse function in that??

Comment: What do you mean with reversing? You should be able to do it manually with a loop.

Comment: Yeah I can do so but as I have mentioned I was solving a question basically it's about rotating a matrix I know we have to transpose the matrix then reverse it but they have used reverse function on arraylist and I just want to know how to do that

Comment: What do you want to reverse? Left/right, top/bottom, across an axis? Please explain what exactly you want.

Comment: interviewbit.com/problems/rotate-matrix

Comment: this is the question I have solved this with array

Answer (score 0):

There are no "matrices" in the Java language in the sense of a two-dimensional structure like `int mat[x,y]`.

You can have an array of arrays (like `int mat[x][y]`) or a list of lists (e.g., `ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>`.  From that you can build matrix-like behaviour.

What's the difference?  Well, for one, an array of arrays is not necessarily rectangular.

Comment: but that's what I want to make a rectangular version

Comment: https://www.interviewbit.com/problems/rotate-matrix/

Comment: this is the question I have solved this with array but in the solution they have solved this with arraylist basically it's about rotating a matrix and they have used reverse function on arraylist and I just want to know how to do this??